# Flutter: Specify and use an asset within a package

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

What's the general approach specifying and referencing an asset within a Flutter/Dart package?

I have tried various approaches and I always get the error `Unable to load asset: path/to/image` when trying to create an image widget: `Image(image: AssetImage('path/to/image'))`.

My goal is to create custom buttons library and some of them should come with custom icons (images).

**I would like to use the images within my own package, not outside in an app** and expose complete button widgets instead.

For example, let's say I'm creating a package called `wolf`:

- `wolf/`
- `wolf/lib/wolf.dart`
- `wolf/lib/src/Wolf.dart`
- `wolf/pubspec.yaml`

Where in the above directory structure do you put an asset, how do you define it in `pubspec.yaml` (if necessary) and how do you use it in `wolf/lib/src/Wolf.dart`?

Comment: you mean like this? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9249

Comment: @RollingPanda Where in that issue are assets used from within a custom package?

Comment: you mean you wanna use assets in your package? or  you wanna access other package's assets in your package? https://medium.com/flutter-community/including-assets-in-a-flutter-package-dd4a82a38ca9  this article may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `pubsec.yaml`, you need to include the assets, like this-

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/logos/google_light.png
    - assets/logos/google_dark.png
```

Create a Widget in your package and use it. Use the name of your package (assuming name of your package is `flutter_mypackage_button`) in the `package` attribute of `AssetImage`, like this-

```
Image(
    image: AssetImage(
        button == Buttons.Google
            ? 'assets/logos/google_light.png'
            : 'assets/logos/google_dark.png',
        package: 'flutter_mypackage_button',
    ),
    height: 36.0,
)
```

I hope this should do it.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but this exact article I have gone through before posting this question and I didn't understand how to use an asset from within a package (not outside a package).

Comment: Thanks @kartoon that's exacly what I was looking for. The key is in the use of the package attribute.

Comment: Hi, I followed the answer but the Exception has occurred. 

```FlutterError (Unable to load asset: packages/flutter_mypackage_button/assets/logos/google_light.png)```